# In .Net, while converting "Image" with another image , then one of the image's color quality is affected

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing

In .net application when the image is processed & merged with another image then its colours are affected.
Image image  ---------> Uploaded image

Bitmap xy = new Bitmap(image, image.Width, image.Height);  -----> Conversion into Bitmap to perform various operations like resize or merge with another image.

So the “image” object has few “PropertyItems” and when we convert image to Bitmap type of object then these “PropertyItems” array is empty, which means these “PropertyItems” were not moved in this conversion.

[image: image with propertyitems]

Now after this image is moved into Bitmap object for merging with another image, then “PropertyItems” array is empty

[image: bitmap image without propertyitems]

Due to loss of these propertyitems, color of the image is changed.

For merging, I'm using below code

```
public string MergeImages(List<BlockPositionDetailsWithSize> blockPositionDetailsWithSize, int layoutWidth, int layoutHeight)
    {
        var bitmap = new Bitmap(layoutWidth-75, layoutHeight);
        float width = 0, height = 0;
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;

            var bitmapImg = blockPositionDetailsWithSize.Where(b => b.BlockId.Contains("fImageBlock")).FirstOrDefault();

           // This loop is placing two images in graphic object
            foreach (var block in blockPositionDetailsWithSize)
            {
                width = block.Width;
                height = block.Height;                    
                g.DrawImage(block.BlockImage, block.PosX, block.PosY, block.Width, block.Height);
            }

        }

        ImageCodecInfo jpgEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg); // change image format 

        System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        bitmap.SetResolution(288, 288);

        System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder imgEncoder = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;
        EncoderParameters imgEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);

        EncoderParameter imgEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(imgEncoder, 95L); //A quality level of 0 corresponds to the greatest compression, and a quality level of 100 corresponds to the least compression.
        imgEncoderParameters.Param[0] = imgEncoderParameter;

        bitmap.Save(ms, jpgEncoder, imgEncoderParameters);


        byte[] byteImage = ms.ToArray();

        string base64String = string.Empty;
        base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage); ////Get Base64

        return base64String;
    }
```

Image's color quality can be maintained by following code

```
foreach (System.Drawing.Imaging.PropertyItem item in bitmapImg.BlockImage.PropertyItems)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        bitmap.SetPropertyItem(item);
                    }
                    catch
                    {

                    }
                }
```

Now the issue is I cannot apply one image's property item on the final image(produced after merging). Because when I apply one image's property items onto another image then the second image's color quality is affected but if I don't apply then the first Image's color quality is affected.

So I am looking for the way to merge two images without loosing of any it's property items.

Comment: If you want to create a new Bitmap identical to the original, `.Clone()` the original (`var bitmap = (Bitmap)[original].Clone();`). If you do something like `var bitmap = new Bitmap([original])`, you'll lose the `PropertyIdList`. If you merge a bunch of Images, you'll lose the `PropertyItems` anyway, since it doesn't make any sense that a new Bitmap can have a `PropertyIdList` that is the sum of all the others. The *merged* Bitmap must have a `PixelFormat = PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb`.

Comment: If you load the original Image from a file or stream, use the form `var image = Image.FromFile(@"[File Path]"), true);`. Note the `true` argument, see what that means.

Comment: @Jimi thanks for your comments. But I'm facing a strange issue, My client has images taken by canon DSLR and when that image is converted into bitmap then it's colour quality is affected, but I tried many other images taken by DSLR but didn't face this issue. What could be the problem with those specific images? Any idea about this?

Comment: Difficult to say without testing the image and comparing it with original Raw format. Most of the time, because the ICM/ICC profile stored in the Image has not been loaded(if it has actually been saved in the Image while onverting from the Raw format), as hinted in my previous comment. Sometimes it happens because the JPG conversion (a JPG should only be used for Preview/File sharing) has been performed in another platform (MacOS, for example) where the color management is different. A low-pass filter of a DSLR may store informations that require a system-specific interpretation.

Comment: Professional software can fill the gap between platforms and correctly interpret an ICM profile and perform the adaptation. GDI+ alone cannot. But this is just guessing.